# Calculate execution time of php command execution (popen() function)

Tags: php, process

I want to calculate the execution time of [popen](https://www.php.net/popen) function in PHP. The function is not provide execution time as default.

My pseudo code like below;

```
    $handle        = popen($cmd, 'r');
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, FREAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
        $out .= $buffer . " ";
    }
```

I found a solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951188/1534223) but I am not sure it's the right way.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It helps to limit with a timeout which set in a while loop. Actually, if the process duration was longer than the timeout, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the time() or microtime(true) function.

```
$currentTimeinSeconds = microtime(true);
```

This stores the seconds passed from the instance it was declared to 1/01/1970. Make two variables (ex. T1 and T2) and simply subtract the second to the first to get the execution time.

```
$t1= microtime(true)
[function]
$t2= microtime(true)
ex_time=$t2-$t1
```

Comment: You probably want `microtime(true)`

Comment: Actually, It is very simple, I don't know, how I forgot but it works thank you so much